# How to record the admin password of my Moodle site

Tags: moodle

I have moodle 2.9.3 installed on ubuntu 14.0.    I am a newbie with ubuntu and moodle.  I have seen other post but they assume you know how to navigate through ubuntu.  I need clear instructions on how to manually change the admin password

Answer (score 4):

- Learn how to open a terminal in Ubuntu and navigate into your file system
- Once you feel you are ready, navigate to `/var/www/html/your-moodle-system/admin/cli/` where "your-moodle-system" is the directory identifying the moodle 2.9.3 system you've installed.
- Type the command `sudo php reset_password.php` and press the Enter key. The system will show the following sentence: *Enter username (manual authentication only)*
- Enter the word `admin` and hit Enter
- Enter your new password and hit Enter

Now you are ready. Try to login into your system with the new credentials.